# Falha ao fazer um alteração no banco de dados

Tags: delphi, postgresql

Quando vou fazer um `Update` na tabela `Impressora` meu programa está se fechando sozinho, ao depurar o programa o seguinte erro foi acusado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu Update está dessa forma:

```
begin
    if cdsImpressora.state in[dsedit] then
    begin
      dmDatabase.SQLConnection.Execute('UPDATE Impressoras SET '+
         ' PATRIMONIO ='''+ cdsImpressoraPATRIMONIO.AsString+''','+
         ' PATRIMONIOBANDEJA = '''+ cdsImpressoraPATRIMONIO.AsString+''','+
         ' PATRIMONIODUPLEX = '''+ cdsImpressoraPATRIMONIODUPLEX.AsString +''','+
         ' PATRIMONIOMAILBOX = '''+ cdsImpressoraPATRIMONIOMAILBOX.AsString +''','+
         ' NUMEROIP = '''+ cdsImpressoraNUMEROIP.AsString + ''','+
         ' ENDERECOEXTERNO = '''+ cdsImpressoraENDERECOEXTERNO.AsString +''','+
         ' NUMERONF = '''+ cdsImpressoraNUMERONF.AsString +''','+
         ' NUMEROPORTA = '''+ cdsImpressoraNUMEROPORTA.AsString+''','+
         ' NUMEROSERIE ='''+ cdsImpressoraNUMEROSERIE.AsString+''','+
         ' SENHA = ''' + cdsImpressoraSENHA.AsString+''','+
         ' USUARIO = ''' + cdsImpressoraUSUARIO.AsString+''','+
         ' CAMINHO = ''' + cdsImpressoraCAMINHO.AsString+''','+
         ' SETORINSTALACAO ='''+ cdsImpressoraSETORINSTALACAO.AsString+ ''',' +
         ' CODIGOMODELO = ' + cdsImpressoraCODIGOMODELO.AsString+ ',' +
         ' FRANQUIA = ' +iif(cdsImpressoraFRANQUIA.AsString='','0',cdsImpressoraFRANQUIA.AsString)+','+
         ' VALORIMPRESSAO = ' +iif(cdsImpressoraVALORIMPRESSAO.AsString='','0',TrocaVirgPPto(cdsImpressoraVALORIMPRESSAO.AsString))+','+
         ' TIPOPATRIMONIO = '''+cdsImpressoraTIPOPATRIMONIO.AsString + ''','+
         ' PATRIMONIOOUTRO = '''+cdsImpressoraPATRIMONIOOUTRO.AsString + ''','+
         ' VALORIMPRESSAOCOLOR = '+iif(cdsImpressoraVALORIMPRESSAOCOLOR.AsString='','0',TrocaVirgPPto(cdsImpressoraVALORIMPRESSAOCOLOR.AsString))+','+
         ' FRANQUIACOLOR = '+ iif(cdsImpressoraFRANQUIACOLOR.AsString='','0',cdsImpressoraFRANQUIACOLOR.AsString)+','+
         ' CORTESIAIMPRESSAO = '+iif(cdsImpressoraCORTESIAIMPRESSAO.AsString='','0',cdsImpressoraCORTESIAIMPRESSAO.AsString)+','+
         ' VALOREXCEDENTEIMPRESSAOCOLOR =' +iif(cdsImpressoraVALOREXCEDENTEIMPRESSAOCOLOR.AsString='','0',TrocaVirgPPto(cdsImpressoraVALOREXCEDENTEIMPRESSAOCOLOR.AsString))+','+
         ' VALORFIXOMENSAL = ' +iif(cdsImpressoraVALORFIXOMENSAL.AsString='','0',TrocaVirgPPto(cdsImpressoraVALORFIXOMENSAL.AsString))+','+
         ' VALOREXCEDENTEDIGITALIZACAO = '+iif(cdsImpressoraVALOREXCEDENTEDIGITALIZACAO.AsString='','0',TrocaVirgPPto(cdsImpressoraVALOREXCEDENTEDIGITALIZACAO.AsString))+','+
         ' VALORDIGITALIZACAO = '+iif(cdsImpressoraVALORDIGITALIZACAO.AsString='','0',TrocaVirgPPto(cdsImpressoraVALORDIGITALIZACAO.AsString))+ ','+
         ' STATUS = '+QuotedStr(cdsImpressorastatus.AsString)+','+ 
         ' FRANQUIADIGITALIZACAO = '+iif(cdsImpressoraFRANQUIADIGITALIZACAO.AsString='','0',TrocaVirgPPto(cdsImpressoraFRANQUIADIGITALIZACAO.AsString))+
         ' where CODIGO = '+cdsImpressoraCODIGO.AsString, nil);
    end;
  end;
  cdsImpressora.Close;
  sdsImpressora.CommandText := 'select * from Impressoras where codigo = 0' ;
  cdsImpressora.Open;
  MostraFila(0);
```

E minha tabela `impressora` está configurada da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se tiverem alguma ideia de o que possa estar ocorrendo. Pois para inserir no banco o erro não ocorre.

Comment: Muito provavelmente um de seus campos inteiros está vazio.
E vejo que você ainda não aprendeu a usar o QuotedStr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu `CODIGOMODELO` é um `integer` no banco e no seu update você não está fazendo o `IIF`

```
' CODIGOMODELO = ' +iif(cdsImpressoraCODIGOMODELO.AsString='','0',cdsImpressoraCODIGOMODELO.AsString)+','+
```

Uma coisa que você pode fazer para lhe ajudar a identificar os problemas. É separar a sua instrução sql em uma variável, e usando o modo debug do delphi, avaliar o valor da variável para identificar possíveis problemas de concatenação.

Uma das formas de inspecionar é no modo debug você apertar a sequência `Ctrl+F7` e usar o `Evaluate/Modify` para ver o valor da variável.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem estou inspecionando a minha variável `update`, podendo copiar o texto que está no `result` e analisar melhor usando alguma ferramente de banco de dados.

Comment: Eu devo usar `iff` se for `Integer` no banco? Desculpe a pergunta é que sou iniciante em Delphi e esse código não fui eu quem desenvolveu

Comment: Digamos que sim, sempre que o campo for integer, tem que montar a instrução passando um integer e como você está usando um AsString, se o valor do campo for `nil` o delphi deixa em branco a tua concatenação. Mas o seu estilo de programação está muito fora de padrões de desenvolvimento que o Delphi proporciona, lhe aconselharia a usar os componentes da paleta `Data Controls` junto com os da `Data Access` e seus `DataSets`. Unindo esses componentes, você não precisa digira uma linha de código se quer para fazer um simples CRUD.

Comment: Outra coisa, se você está iniciando com Delphi, pq Delphi? Eu particularmente já não inicio mais nenhum projeto em Delphi, meus novos projetos são todos em C#.

Comment: Sim, na verdade eu sugeri que fosse atualizado para Java que é uma linguagem que tenho mais domínio porém fui instruído a apenas fazer as alterações necessárias em delphi mesmo

Comment: Fiz essa alteração que tu sugeriu na tua resposta, porém o mesmo erro continuou ocorrendo

Comment: Fiz uma edição na resposta

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51707/discussion-between-pablo-vargas-and-r-santos).

Answer (score 0):

Faz um theparam entre banco e seu update para que você consiga identificar qual é o campo que esta causando o erro de conversão.

Uma técnica que utilizo nesse caso é tirar um pedaço do update e deixar poucos campos e ir adicionando os outros gradativamente , dessa forma você verá qual campo esta dando o problema.