# Erro ao alterar dados antigos do Banco

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi

Com o auxilio dessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177188/falha-ao-fazer-um-altera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-banco-de-dados/177226#177226) consegui editar os dados que insiro no banco, porém os dados antigos que já estão cadastrados, quando tento alterar o cadastro, o programa continua a fechar sozinho e ao depurar exibe a seguinte mensagem de erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E se continuo depurando o erro passa a ser:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fui depurando o código e o erro está ocorrendo na `procedure` **Envio_ftp**, minha `procedure` esta assim:

```
procedure TfrmCriarArquivo.Envio_ftp(grupo, cliente: string);
begin
  with FTP do try
    Username := frmMenu.usuario;
    Password := frmMenu.senha;
    Host := frmMenu.endereco;
    Port := StrtoInt(frmMenu.porta);
    Connect;
    try
      ChangeDir(grupo);
    except
      FTP.MakeDir(grupo);
      ChangeDir(grupo);
    end;
    try
      FTP.Put('dados.ini', 'dados.ini', false);
    except
    end;
    try
      ChangeDir(grupo + '/' + cliente);
    except
      FTP.MakeDir(grupo + '/' + cliente);
      ChangeDir(grupo + '/' + cliente);
    end;
  except
    application.Terminate;
  end;
  try
    FTP.Put(cliente + '.xml', cliente + '.xml', False);
    FTP.Put('Tags' + '_' + cliente + '.txt', 'Tags' + '_' + cliente + '.txt', false);
  finally
    FTP.Disconnect;
  end;
  DeleteFile(cliente + '.xml');
  DeleteFile('Tags' + '_' + cliente + '.txt');
  DeleteFile('dados.ini');
end;
```

Lembrando que isso só acontece quando tento alterar os cadastros antigos do banco.

Erro Novo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e como ficou a `procedure` após a alteração:

```
with FTP do try
    Username := frmMenu.usuario;
    Password := frmMenu.senha;
    Host := frmMenu.endereco;
    Port := StrtoInt(frmMenu.porta);
    Connect;
    try
      ChangeDir(grupo);
    except
      FTP.MakeDir(grupo);
      ChangeDir(grupo);
    end;
    try
      FTP.Put('dados.ini', 'dados.ini', false);
    except
    end;
    try
      ChangeDir(grupo + '/' + cliente);
    except
      FTP.MakeDir(grupo + '/' + cliente);
      ChangeDir(grupo + '/' + cliente);
    end;
  except
    application.Terminate;
  end;
```

Comment: Olhando por cima, o único lugar que faz sentido dar EConvertError neste fonte é no `StrtoInt`. Tem certeza que `frmMenu.porta` está preenchido?

Comment: @Genos Sou iniciante em Delphi e esse código é legado, depurei agora novamente o código e quando passo o cursor do mouse em cima dessa  linha `frm.porta` me mostra `''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EConvertError` (a exceção indicada na sua mensagem) geralmente acontece quando se tenta converter um tipo de valor em outro. No seu caso está acontecendo por causa da linha:

```
StrtoInt(frmMenu.porta)
```

`StrToInt` é um método que converte uma string para um número inteiro. Conforme comentado, `frmMenu.porta` contém o valor `''`(string vazia). Como o método não consegue converter `''` para um número, acontece este erro.

Para resolver, identifique se é de fato possível `frmMenu.porta` estar vazio.

- Caso sim, cheque o valor do campo antes da conversão e trate-o:

  ```
  if frmMenu.porta = '' then
    // Por exemplo, usar uma porta padrão...
    Port := 20
  else
    Port := StrtoInt(frmMenu.porta);
  ```
- Caso contrário, identifique o porquê do campo `frmMenu.porta` estar vazio e resolva esta situação.

Comment: Fiz a alteração que tu sugeriu em sua resposta e deu um erro diferente durante a execução e continuou fechando a aplicação. Editei a pergunta original com a imagem do novo erro

Comment: Ai provavelmente é erro de conexão, cheque se você está usando o host/porta certos, entre outras configurações. Sem informações mais detalhadas é o máximo que eu consigo te ajudar.